# IIS Managed Module in .NET4

Tags: .net-4.0, module, iis-7.5

I want to write a Managed Module for IIS 7.5 using .NET 4.0 because I want to use the new MemoryMappedFile class.
I started with a small prototype compiled with .NET 4.0 and tried to integrate it into the IIS without success.
The module is strong-named and I could install it into the GAC. After that I added it through the IIS Manager but the worker process doesn't seem to load it as I cannot debug the module by attaching the debugger to w3wp.exe. The AppPool also runs with .NET 4.0.
Any ideas about that?
Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I had to uncheck the "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers" checkbox. After that the module worked as expected.